# Минимальный размер QWidget с учетом содержимого

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer

Мне необходимо чтобы виджет занимал минимально возможное пространство, но с учетом того, что он не может быть меньше, чем его содержимое.
Его содержимое два QLabel. Верхний с картинкой, нижний с текстом, длина которого может быть различна. На последнем скрине, то что надо получить: красная рамка - граница виджета, которая должна быть не меньше, но и не больше своего содержимого.

Игрался с различными вариациями sizePolicy для виджета и всего его содержимого, но это ни к чему не привело. Максимум чего удалось добиться это срезанный по горизонтальным краям текст и более-менее нормально выглядящая картинка, да и та, только благодаря тому, что я задал в дизайнере минимальный размер QLabel под эту картинку. Кьют ведь сам должен понимать свое содержимое, почему я сам должен как-то жестко задавать размеры? Это неправильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Что надо получить]

Comment: вероятно ты хочешь установить `QSizePolicy::Fixed` или `QSizePolicy::Maximum` для внешнего виджета... но это несколько сложно сказать не видя конкретики...

Comment: Я могу расписать подробнее, только не знаю, что именно требуется для конкретики. Красная точка - картинка внутри пиксмапа, который внутри labelImagePoint. Обрезанные цифры(0:1), что ниже красной точки - текст внутри labelTextGamePoint, текст обрезался(в этом и проблема). Оба они находятся в виджете, который отрисовывается поверх другого виджета - основного(на картинке выглядит, как карта).

Comment: Мне все, что необходимо это - чтобы внешний виджет(точка и текст) были максимально друг к другу скомпанованы(что сейчас и происходит), но чтобы текст не обрезался. И что бы сама граница этого виджета была минимального размера. Добавил еще скрин того, что хотелось бы получить. Красным - граница виджета. Граница должна быть минимальна, потому что виджет подразумевает кликабельность в своей области.

Comment: Убери у всех виджетов явно заданные `geometry`, `sizePolicy` и `minimumSize`, а у верхнего установи `sizePolicy` в `QSizePolicy::Fixed` — скорей всего должно сработать... ЗЫ: судя по оригинальной задаче это хорошее время, чтобы освоить фреймворк `QGraphicsScene` вместо онанизма с обычными виджетами...

Comment: Не помогает, чтобы я там не выставил у верхнего виджета, результат - срезанный текст. QGraphicsScene я уже пробовал, там возникают свои заморочки и проблемы в моем случае, текущий вариант пока еще самый рабочий.

Comment: нуда... забыл, что `sizePolicy` работает только для виджетов внутри `layout`'ов... у тебя же они просто-так вручную разбросаны?.. в таком случае `resize (sizeHint());` в конструкторе спасёт отца русской демократии...

Comment: Помогло! Благодарю!